# How can I fill an array with the Ok value of a Result from a function call or return the Err?

Tags: arrays, rust, initialization

Consider the case where a function returns a `Result`:

```
fn might_explode() -> Result<AllFine, Kaboom> {
    // Awesome, potentially explosive things.
}
```

Let us assume that I have no control, and I cannot make assumptions, over `AllFine` (e.g., it comes from another crate). What I would like to do is to fill, if possible, an array of `AllFine` with values obtained by iteratively invoking `might_explode()`. If any of the invocations to `might_explode()` returns an `Err`, I would like to return that `Err`.

For example, if I wanted to build an array of four elements, I would do:

```
let my_array = [might_explode()?, might_explode()?, might_explode()?, might_explode()?]
```

The above indeed works nicely, but for large arrays (I will be working, e.g., with arrays as big as 256 elements) it becomes extremely cumbersome and (I guess?) it makes the resulting binary very bloated.

Looking around for possible solutions, I stumbled upon [this beautiful post](https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/array-initialization-rust/) that seems to do exactly what I need. Using a bit of `unsafe`, the post above presents this example:

```
let _: [Option<String>; 33] = unsafe {
    let mut arr: [Option<String>; 33] = std::mem::uninitialized();
    for item in &mut arr[..] {
        std::ptr::write(item, None);
    }
    arr
};
```

Now, this would be just perfect for me if only `might_explode()` always returned `AllFine`. But sometimes it might return `Kaboom`! As a result, I might be caught halfway through the initialization of the array, and in returning I'd call a potentially deadly `drop` on every non-initialized element of the array.

So, is there a way to reasonably use `unsafe` to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=273435376ac8a605b528eb3a7a29a778)

Comment: *I might be caught halfway through the initialization of the array* — yes; don't write that code yourself because it's **very** difficult to get correct.